# Bootstrap responsive navigation bar questions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, navigationbar

I have [this code](https://goo.gl/6R9Vaq) for a bootstrap responsive navgation bar. In desktop view, the logo is at the, top, which is fine, but in the mobile view, I want the logo to appear inline with the expand button. How would I go about doing this?

PS: Resize the preview window in jsfiddle to see the responsive format. The expand button in mobile view doesn't work in jsfiddle either.

Also, how could I change the colour scheme on my navigation bar with css?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add a CSS style to navbar-header{ float: right;}

```css
.navbar-header {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
    </div>
    <center>
      <p id="LOGO">
        <img src="http://codingkids.businesscatalyst.com/logo.png" width="50%" alt="Coding Kids">
      </p>
    </center>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Silver</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Silver+</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gold</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gold+</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And about the color scheme. I'm not too sure what you exactly mean by that but I'l give it a guess.

I will assume you just want to change the background-color of your content.

Here you can just add more CSS styles to change color.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: You were faster than me. :) Good and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to do this. Put your `img` inside the `navbar-header` and apply the `navbar-brand` class to it. See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

*Sidenote: The `center` tag is not supported in HTML5. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

> This tag has been deprecated in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1) in favor of the
>   CSS text-align property, which can be applied to the `<div>` element or
>   to an individual `<p>`. For centering blocks, use other CSS properties
>   like margin-left and margin-right and set them to auto (or set margin
>   to 0 auto).

See working Snippet.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-brand img {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 6px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-brand img {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://codingkids.businesscatalyst.com/logo.png" alt="Coding Kids">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Silver</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Silver+</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gold</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gold+</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```